# VHDL equal operator: different behavior for std_logic and std_ulogic

Tags: vhdl, behavior, modelsim

I have two designs:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity eq_test1 is

  port (a,b : IN std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
        o   : OUT std_logic); 
end eq_test1;

architecture strange_behavior of eq_test1 is
begin  
    P: process (a,b)
    begin
        if a = b then o <= '1';
        else o <= '0';
        end if;
    end process P;
end strange_behavior;
```

Forcing in Modelsim to a have "00" and b have "0L" shows that o becomes '0'.
So L is NOT interpreted as 0, "00" = "0L" is false. Ok.

But when I take the same design and add

```
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
```

to the list, the behavior is different.
Then "00" = "0L" returns true, so L IS the same as 0 (0 becomes '1').
With that unsigned packages included, even "0X" = "0Z" returns true.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: L is pull-down, meaning: connection to ground via resistor. if you insert it to a gate it will be interrupted as '0' (same as verilog's "weak 0"). the reason it needs the unsigned is because the VHDL is strongly typed and you need a special function to convert 'L' to '0'

Comment: you can take a look at the std_logic_unsigned package (easy to access it via modelsim - just pick ieee -> the lib) and see which of the functions defined there agrees that '0' = 'L'

Comment: ok, thx. I will. that might help to understand the difference between the two equal operators

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;` is like opening Pandora's box to
Synopsys libraries.  After a deep dive shown below, the conclusion is that the
std_logic_unsigned package in this case makes the values '0' and 'L' equal
through an table.

The call starts when the "=" operator is redefined to:

```
function "="(L: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR; R: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR) return BOOLEAN is
begin
    return   UNSIGNED(L) = UNSIGNED(R);
end;
```

That is however just the beginning, since std_logic_unsigned includes
`use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;`, which defined the type:

```
type UNSIGNED is array (NATURAL range <>) of STD_LOGIC;
```

The compare of UNSIGNED in "=" thus result in call of std_logic_arith function:

```
function "="(L: UNSIGNED; R: UNSIGNED) return BOOLEAN is
    -- synopsys subpgm_id 341
    constant length: INTEGER := max(L'length, R'length);
begin
    return bitwise_eql( STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR( CONV_UNSIGNED(L, length) ),
            STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR( CONV_UNSIGNED(R, length) ) );
end;
```

In this function the CONV_UNSIGNED is interesting:

```
function CONV_UNSIGNED(ARG: UNSIGNED; SIZE: INTEGER) return UNSIGNED is
    constant msb: INTEGER := min(ARG'length, SIZE) - 1;
    subtype rtype is UNSIGNED (SIZE-1 downto 0);
    variable new_bounds: UNSIGNED (ARG'length-1 downto 0);
    variable result: rtype;
    -- synopsys built_in SYN_ZERO_EXTEND
    -- synopsys subpgm_id 372
begin
    -- synopsys synthesis_off
    new_bounds := MAKE_BINARY(ARG);
    if (new_bounds(0) = 'X') then
        result := rtype'(others => 'X');
        return result;
    end if;
    result := rtype'(others => '0');
    result(msb downto 0) := new_bounds(msb downto 0);
    return result;
    -- synopsys synthesis_on
end;
```

Now we are getting close, since the above calls:

```
function MAKE_BINARY(A : UNSIGNED) return UNSIGNED is
    -- synopsys built_in SYN_FEED_THRU
    variable one_bit : STD_ULOGIC;
    variable result : UNSIGNED (A'range);
begin
    -- synopsys synthesis_off
        for i in A'range loop
            if (IS_X(A(i))) then
                assert false
                report "There is an 'U'|'X'|'W'|'Z'|'-' in an arithmetic operand, the result will be 'X'(es)."
                severity warning;
                result := (others => 'X');
                return result;
            end if;
            result(i) := tbl_BINARY(A(i));
        end loop;
        return result;
    -- synopsys synthesis_on
end;
```

And in here we have the reason for 'L' being equal to '0', since the tbl_BINARY
is a constant defined as:

```
type tbl_type is array (STD_ULOGIC) of STD_ULOGIC;
constant tbl_BINARY : tbl_type :=
    ('X', 'X', '0', '1', 'X', 'X', '0', '1', 'X');
```

To understand this mapping, it is useful to align with the definition of
values in STD_ULOGIC:

```
std_ulogic: ( 'U', 'X', '0', '1', 'Z', 'W', 'L', 'H', '-');

tbl_BINARY: ( 'X', 'X', '0', '1', 'X', 'X', '0', '1', 'X');
```

This shows that after conversion through tbl_BINARY then the equivalent groups
are ('U', 'X', 'Z', 'W', '-'), ('0', 'L'), and ('1', 'H').

A closing comment is that even through the std_logic_unsigned package resides
in a library called "ieee", the package is not IEEE standard like VHDL, but a
Synopsys package.  The package, and the other related Synopsys packages, have
been around for a while and are widely used.

However, you may consider using the IEEE standard package numeric_std instead.

Comment: what do you consider so evil about std_logic_unsigned?

Comment: std_logic_unsigned is non-standard, so designers may worst case end up using one version of a std_logic_unsigned package in their simulator, and another version in their synthesis tool, with the worst case result that the simulation behavior does not hardware (synthesis) behavior.  If the test rely on simulation, the result can worst case be that you sign off an ASIC that works in simulation, but does not work in real world hardware.  The idea with a standard should be that behavior is well defined to avoid such differences.

Comment: The 'evil':  IEEE Std 1076-2008, 9.2.1 Relational operators, 3rd para, 2nd sentence - "Two composite values of the same type are equal if and only if for each element of the left operand there is a matching element of the right operand and vice versa, and the values of matching elements are equal, as given by the predefined equality operator for the element type."  Composite meaning std_logic_vector in this case. See Para 2, 1st sentence "The equality and inequality operators (= and /=) are defined for all types other than file types and protected types." bitwise_eql violates "as given by".

Comment: And about now you can get an idea why -2008 adds the matching equality operator (?=) which gives the same answer as std_logic_unsigned "=".  The 3rd para 2nd sentence has been in the standard since -1987.

Comment: I think this all "std_logic_unsigned" is evil depends really on what you do. If you just use "STD_LOGIC_VECTOR" as a bit vector (only containing "0" and "1" elements), AND you only want to do unsigned arithmetic (and not both in the same entity/architecture), then std_logic_unsigned is pretty convenient (since you do not need to typecast between "UNSIGNED"/"SIGNED"/"STD_LOGIC_VECTOR" as you have to do with numeric_std.) If you of course use STD_LOGIC_VECTOR in more complicated ways then you are in trouble. But then you are anyway in trouble because it is not clear what synthesis will do...

Comment: @IngoBlackman: The `std_logic_unsigned` is still a non-standard Synopsys package, so even if "convenient" there is the risk as mentioned in first comment, so consider using the IEEE VHDL std. `numeric_std_unsigned` instead.  Btw. can't see why it is not clear what synthesis will do; synthesis will do just what any function describes.

Comment: @MortenZilmer: What will the synthesis do with the following lines of VHDL code (all signals vecX are STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0)): vec1<="L0HX"; vec2<="HZLU"; vec3<="0000" when vec1=vec2 else "1111"; for simulation this is fine (with the caveats of std_logic_unsigned). For synthesis I do not even know if this is accepted at all and much less what the synthesis will make out of these statements.

Comment: I understand that "std_logic_unsigned" is not standardized by IEEE. On the other hand I have not found a single tool which does NOT work as expected with it. Just because "numeric_std" is standardized by the IEEE, does not mean that all tools will behave the same (it is easily possible that a tool has a bug...). If you look at resolution functions: These are also standardized in the language itself and I still do not know of a single synthesis tool which supports resolution functions. So just because something is standardized by IEEE does not mean much for me in practice.

Comment: @IngoBlackman: OK, regarding use of 'L', 'H', and 'U', I wouldn't use it in synthesis, so you are probably right that it is uncertain what tools will do about such values; hopefully report them :-)  About use of Synopsys std_logic_unsigned package, then when it is non-standardized, what is the expected behavior of the package?  And would you rather chose standard numeric_std package, than non-standard std_logic_unsigned package, if making a pacemaker or rocket control ;-)?  Finally, multiple drivers of same signals is not supported by synthesis tools, so resolution functions are not relevant.

Comment: @MortenZilmer: My point was exactly that if you only put "0" and "1" into STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (because this is the only thing really supported by synthesis), then using "std_logic_unsigned" is fine. If I would build a rocket control, I would probably first test my tools thoroughly, REGARDLESS of using "numeric_std" or "std_logic_unsigned". I am wondering: I have heard many times that there might be nasty "surprises" when using std_logic_unsigned and switching between tools. Is this just urban myth or is there actually an example (when only using "0" + "1" in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR) ?

Comment: I have not heard of actual problems using the Synopsys non-standard std_logic_unsigned package, but think it is still relevant to note that the package is not IEEE endorsed, so having it under the IEEE library is misleading.  Btw. in addition to 0 and 1 in synthesis, then Z is also usable for external pins if the IO driver supports Z-state.  Also, X may be useful internally since some synthesis tools can sometimes use the X as don't care and thus optimize the circuit, while simulation tools will still show as X.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the definition of [std_logic_unsigned](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~ggbaker/reference/std_logic/unsigned/std_logic_unsigned.vhd). It replaces the original definition of "=" as follows

```
function "="(L: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR; R: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR) return BOOLEAN is
begin
    return   UNSIGNED(L) = UNSIGNED(R);
end;
```

and as the type UNSIGNED is an integer type which does not know the literals 'h', and 'l', it is accordingly resolved to an integer value, and thus 'l' becomes '0', the semantic equivalent in UNSIGNED

Comment: The UNSIGNED type is not an integer type, but still a bit array, but a bit array that can be interpreted as an unsigned value when used in certain arithmetic operations.  The bits in UNSIGNED can therefore still have bits with values as STD_LOGIC, like 'L', 'X', and 'Z', and there is no length limitations, like 31 bits for the integer type.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that `std_logic_unsigned`, as well as its intended replacement `numeric_std_unsigned`, properly handle 'H' and 'L' as '1' and '0'.

The "unsigned" packages treat std_logic_unsigned as an unsigned numeric value.  Here are some benefits:

- Proper handling of 'H' and 'L'
- Numeric handling of inputs, especially when they are different sizes
- Support mixing std_logic_vector with integers (`Addr = 0`) rather than (`Addr = "0000"`)
- Overloads >, >=, <, <= so they do math ordering rather than dictionary ordering.  Important if sizes are different.

Until vendors (synthesis) implement the VHDL-2008 matching relational operators, `?= ?/= ?> ?>= ?<` and `?<=`, I recommend that you use one of these packages.  When they implement the matching relationals, I recommend using them in new designs.

For more on the VHDL-2008 features, see http://www.synthworks.com/blog/vhdl-standards/

Comment: "Until vendors (synthesis)", or use FUNCTION To_X01Z ( s : std_logic_vector  ) RETURN  std_logic_vector; in std_logic_1164, called a 'strength stripper'.